# Android 'make' error

Tags: android, ubuntu, makefile

I am trying to build an AOSP Rom for my Xperia Z4 tablet. During 'making' it I got an error. It seems like a missing file.

Here's the log file:

```
FindEmulator: find: `frameworks/support/design/dummy': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `frameworks/support/percent/dummy': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `frameworks/support/v14/preference/dummy': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `frameworks/support/v17/leanback/dummy': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `frameworks/support/v17/preference-leanback/dummy': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `frameworks/support/v7/preference/dummy': No such file or directory
FindEmulator: find: `frameworks/support/v7/recyclerview/dummy': No such file or directory
including ./frameworks/volley/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/webview/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/wilhelm/src/Android.mk ...
including ./frameworks/wilhelm/tests/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/akm/AK8975_FS/akmdfs/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/akm/AK8975_FS/libsensors/Android.mk ...
including ./hardware/broadcom/libbt/Android.mk ...
hardware/broadcom/libbt/vnd_buildcfg.mk:3: *** missing separator.
build/core/ninja.mk:134: recipe for target 'out/build-aosp_sgp771.ninja' failed
make: *** [out/build-aosp_sgp771.ninja] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (22 seconds) ####
```